# Log out click, refreshes Page, then only Log out works

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, logout

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.
When ever I Log in and keep the page open for serveral minutes ( about 20 mins or so) and click Log Out. It just refreshes the page, then again I have to click Log out to actually Log out.

Here is a flow chart:

```
Log In--> Stay for 20 mins--> Log Out --> Refreshs page --> Again Log Out --> Logs out
```

here is the Log Out Action

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize]
 [AntiForgeryHandleError]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult LogOff()
 {
     AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```

There is no error, just refresh of the page.

Comment: Have you tried to call :
`AuthenticationManager.Signout(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

Comment: please explain a bit more..